# How can I log messages from an ASP.NET Core application to a specific file on Linux?

Tags: linux, asp.net-core, .net-core

I installed an ASP.NET Core application as a Linux daemon. By default .NET writes logs into `/var/log/message` but I would like the application to write its logs in a specific file and store it permanently.

How I can do this? The application uses `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging`.

Comment: Why do you want to change folders? You migtht want to look into log aggregators like fluentd for docker containers.

Comment: @illug this has nothing to do with log aggregators or containers. `/var/log/message` isn't even used by file logging providers, it's the location used by the *debug* logging provider only only. Another provider could target an aggregator *in addition* to other targets

Comment: Did you try a soution like serilog?  It can handle a lot of different writers like files, rolling files, elasticsearch, database, etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Logs go where you tell them to go, not a specific location. `/var/log/message` is the location used by the [Debug Provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-2.0&tabs=aspnetcore2x#the-debug-provider) only.

You need to specify which logging providers you want to use in the logging configuration of your project, as shown in the [Logging in .NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=aspnetcore2x#how-to-add-providers) article.

There's no [built-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-2.0&tabs=aspnetcore2x#built-in-logging-providers) file provider and there's an [ongoing discussion](https://github.com/aspnet/Logging/issues/441) about whether there should be one. Logging to files isn't as simple as it sounds at first - how should the messages be formatted? What about rolling files? File names? Perhaps you want errors and verbose messages to be written to *different* files? Or use different files per subsystem/area/logger/business  in your application, eg one log for the sales service, another to log external service calls?

There are a *lot* of good open source logging libraries, like Serilog and NLog that address these concerns. Some of the most popular ones are [listed in .NET Core's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-2.0&tabs=aspnetcore2x#third-party-logging-providers). .NET Core's logging can be configured to easily use those libraries.

For example, you can add a [Serilog file target](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-extensions-logging-file) with the appropriate [package](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-extensions-logging-file).

To use it, you need to add a reference to the package, eg in your `csproj` file :

```
<PackageReference Include="Serilog.Extensions.Logging.File" Version="2.0.0" />
```

And add it to the logging configuration with a call to `AddFile` :

```
WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureLogging((hostingContext, logging) =>
    {
        logging.AddFile("path/to/Logs/myapp-{Date}.txt");
    })
    .UseStartup<Startup>()
    .Build();
```

The `{Date}` argument is used to create rolling log files per date.

You can combine multiple loggers,eg you can write to the console with `logging.AddConsole()` or keep writing to `/var/log/message` during development with `logging.AddDebug();`

You can find many logging providers is you search for [Extensions.Logging](https://www.nuget.org/packages?page=2&q=extensions.logging) in NuGet.

You could also integrate other libraries like Serilog in your application and use their loggers. For example, you can use the [Serilog.Sinks.Fluentd](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Serilog.Sinks.Fluentd/) package to target Fluentd

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 20.04, and there is a file called `/var/log/syslog` but the .net 6 logs don't exist in it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

> By default dotnet write logs into /var/log/message

Only if you use the "Debug logging provider" that simply logs calls to `Debug.WriteLine`. These calls are ignored in "release" builds, the compiler simply removes them from your app unless you have the `DEBUG` build constant.

Now back to the question: I was also kinda surprised there's no built-in logging in .NET 5 for Linux.

Especially considering that Linux has had *great* built-in logging tools for decades. Like `syslog` for example. Just send stuff to the `/dev/log` socket and linux will take care of the rest - write to a file, rotate logs, etc etc.

So I wrote a (very!) short C# file that just calls the built-in `syslog()` function from `libc` using `DllImport`.

It's not a huge Nuget dependency, not a "logging provider", not a DI-service or whatever. Just one 1kb C# file you can throw into your project and log stuff like this:

```cs
Syslog.Write(Syslog.Level.Warning, "MyAwesomeApp", "something went wrong");
```

Here's the gist https://github.com/jitbit/SyslogCore

P.S. This does not directly answer the question, but this page keeps popping up when I search for ways to log under Linux in .NET 5. So I decided to post another answer.

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 20.04, and there is a file called `/var/log/syslog` but the .net 6 logs don't exist in it. Any ideas?

Comment: @variable please check the FAQ at the linked repo and file a github issue if something's not working

Comment: @AlexfromJitbit As commented out by variable there is no log in /var/log/syslog which is owned by syslog:adm. But dotnet requires www-data. I simply need debug log which prints when we start the app `dotnet -d app.dll` to figure out why my app is hanging during 20 req/sec/. Can you clarify on that ?