# Deployed ASP.NET Core 5.0 to Ubuntu 20.04 and am getting 500 server error and white screen

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, ubuntu, nginx

I’m trying to run ASP.Net Core 5.0 on Ubuntu 20.04 server and I’m getting a white screen after everything is running. Network tab in FireFox is giving the `HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error`, so Ive been searching the internet for the last two weeks trying to figure this out before coming to SO.

Here is how I have everything configured as of right now.

I created a `Ubuntu 20.04 LTS x64` droplet on Digital Ocean and installed `Nginx`.

[Here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-nginx-on-ubuntu-20-04) are the steps I took to install Nginx and get it running.

Installed all the needed Microsoft packages like the [SDK and Runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-ubuntu#2004-)

Everything was up and running I could see the normal Nginx Welcome screen. Created a server block and added an Index.html file and could see that just fine as well.

Then I created a directory like so `sudo mkdir -p /var/www/myDomainName`
also giving my self the needed permissions

cloned my repo from GitHub to the newly created `dir` which has the needed [Forwarding Headers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/proxy-load-balancer?view=aspnetcore-5.0#fhmo) middleware changes to the startup.cs as stated in the Microsoft docs.

I run the `dotnet build` command and get the following.

```
/var/www/myDomain/src/Presentation/CTA.Web$ dotnet build
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.11.2+f32259642 for .NET
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Determining projects to restore...
All projects are up-to-date for restore.
CTA.Web -> /var/www/myDomain/src/Presentation/CTA.Web/bin/Debug/net5.0/CTA.Web.dll
CTA.Web -> /var/www/myDomain/src/Presentation/CTA.Web/bin/Debug/net5.0/CTA.Web.Views.dll

Build succeeded.
  0 Warning(s)
  0 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:02.25
```

Then I run the `dotnet publish` command and get the following

```
/var/www/myDomain/src/Presentation/CTA.Web$ dotnet publish
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.11.2+f32259642 for .NET
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Determining projects to restore...
All projects are up-to-date for restore.
CTA.Web -> /var/www/myDomain/src/Presentation/CTA.Web/bin/Debug/net5.0/CTA.Web.dll
CTA.Web -> /var/www/myDomain/src/Presentation/CTA.Web/bin/Debug/net5.0/CTA.Web.Views.dll
CTA.Web -> /var/www/myDomain/src/Presentation/CTA.Web/bin/Debug/net5.0/publish/
```

Then I configure the server by creating and editing my server block which shows this:

```
server {

    server_name myDomain.com www.myDomain.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/myDomain.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/myDomain.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}

server {
if ($host = www.myDomain.com) {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
} # managed by Certbot


if ($host = myDomain.com) {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
} # managed by Certbot


   listen 80 ;
   listen [::]:80 ;
#server_name myDomain.com www.myDomain.com;
return 404; # managed by Certbot
```

I run the `sudo nginx -s reload` command as well.

in the `/etc/systemd/system` I created a myDomain.service file and added the following.

```
[Unit]
Description=Archery app

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/var/www/myDomain
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dotnet /var/www/myDomain/src/Presentation/CTA.Web/bin/Debug/net5.0/publish/CTA.Web.dll
Restart=always
RestartSec=10
SyslogIdentifier=archery
User=myUsername
Environment=ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production
Environment=DOTNET_PRINT_TELEMETRY_MESSAGE=false

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I run the 3 commands

```
sudo systemctl enable myDomain.service    
sudo systemctl start myDomain.service    
sudo systemctl status myDomain.service
```

and here is what I get for the status

```
myDomain.service - Archery app
 Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/myDomain.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
 Active: active (running) since Sun 2021-12-12 02:38:49 UTC; 3 days ago
 Main PID: 28005 (dotnet)
 Tasks: 11 (limit: 1136)
 Memory: 51.7M
 CGroup: /system.slice/myDomain.service
         └─28005 /usr/bin/dotnet /var/www/myDomain/src/Presentation/CTA.Web/bin/Debug/net5.0/publish/CTA.Web.dll

 Dec 15 02:28:27 eComArchery archery[28005]: at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)
 Dec 15 02:28:27 eComArchery archery[28005]: at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
 Dec 15 02:28:27 eComArchery archery[28005]: at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
 Dec 15 02:28:27 eComArchery archery[28005]: at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
 Dec 15 02:28:27 eComArchery archery[28005]: at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.<Invoke>g__Awaited|6_0(ExceptionHandlerMiddleware middleware, HttpContext context, >Dec 15 02:28:27 eComArchery archery[28005]: at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.HandleException(HttpContext context, ExceptionDispatchInfo edi)
 Dec 15 02:28:27 eComArchery archery[28005]: at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.<Invoke>g__Awaited|6_0(ExceptionHandlerMiddleware middleware, HttpContext context, >Dec 15 02:28:27 eComArchery archery[28005]: at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.ProcessRequests[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application)
 Dec 15 02:28:27 eComArchery archery[28005]: info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[2]
 Dec 15 02:28:27 eComArchery archery[28005]: Request finished HTTP/1.1 GET http://example.com/ - - - 500 0 - 32.0811ms
```

If there is anythign else anyone would like to see let me know.

Comment: at the very end I have to change the `Dec 15 02:28:27 eComArchery archery[28005]: Request finished HTTP/1.1 GET http://myDomain. com/ - - - 500 0 - 32.0811ms` to `example.com` stackoverflows rules.

Comment: I notice the error stack were coming from Authentication and Authorization, have you correctly setup on those two dependency injection?

Comment: this link may help you https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/fix-http-1-1-500-internal-server-error-error-when-you-download-a-large-file-from-an-iis-7-5-website-if-the-sf-notify-send-raw-data-notification-is-registered-in-an-isapi-filter-50256d93-04f5-22b2-d6da-2e5be35c2f22

Answer (score 3):

You have an internal server error, It's not an error from the server config. The application return a 500.
In terminal you can write

`journalctl -u [YourServiceName].service --since '2021-MM-DD hh:mm:ss'`

to get the lasts errors of your app. Fix it, re-deploy.

Answer (score 1):

Note that you may have a correct server configuration as internal server errors may come from other reasons.

You have to see what happens in the background by enabling logs. For this, see the [How i can logging messages from asp.net core application in specific file on linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50483277/1743997) and [Logging in .NET Core and ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-6.0) to know how to enable it on linux.
And then you can find the main problems.

Comment: `web.config`? OP is talking about .NET Core app

Comment: @AndrewSilver Thanks for your comment. It was an instruction for IIS and I changed it