# Database error after publishing in Digital Ocean

Tags: c#, sqlite, asp.net-core, nginx, digital-ocean

I am trying to host an ASP.NET Core Web API in Digital Ocean Ubuntu 22.04 droplet with Nginx. It uses SQLite. When I run the `dotnet build | dotnet run` commands everything works fine, Swagger opens, and the data is retrieved from the database.

However, after I publish using the `dotnet publish`, create a service in `/etc/systemd/system` and run it with `sudo systemctl start myapi.service`, Swagger opens successfully, but any HTTP request results in "Error 500: internal service error".

The service file :

```
[Unit]
Description=My API

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/home/myAPI/bin/Debug/net6.0/publish
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dotnet /home/myAPI/bin/Debug/net6.0/publish/myAPI.dll
Restart=always
# Restart service after 10 seconds if the dotnet service crashes:
RestartSec=10
KillSignal=SIGINT
SyslogIdentifier=dotnet-example
User=www-data
Environment=ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production
Environment=DOTNET_PRINT_TELEMETRY_MESSAGE=false

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running the command

```
journalctl -u [YourServiceName].service --since '2021-MM-DD hh:mm:ss'
```

helped to see that the actual error was 'SQLite attempt to write a readonly database'.
The solution was to change `User=www-data` to `User=root` in the service file.

Answer (score 1):

You have an internal server error, It's not an error from the server config. The application return a 500. In terminal you can write:

```
journalctl -u [YourServiceName].service --since '2021-MM-DD hh:mm:ss'
```

to get the lasts errors of your app. Fix it, re-deploy.

You can also see what's happening in the background by enabling logging. Here are two reference documents:

[How can I log messages from an ASP.NET Core application to a specific file on Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50483277/how-can-i-log-messages-from-an-asp-net-core-application-to-a-specific-file-on-li).

[Logging in .NET Core and ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-6.0).

Hope this can help you.